# Find minimum value of variables using only max function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to find the minimum value of A and B variables but only using the max function

Comment: Do you have a question? This does not seem like complicated problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use if-else statement

```
minab=B if max(A,B)==A alse A
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want it, but you can:

```
min_a_b = A + B - max(A, B)
```